# How to import vue methods to a component from another ts file

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a vue component and import methods from another ts file. there are methods in the test.ts and test2.ts files that my component needs. I am trying to separate methods into different files. in vue component i import test.ts , when i call these methods from component - everything works. Next, I want to add methods from the test2.ts file to the test.ts file. and if I call the methods of the test2.ts file from the component, everything also works. but when I try to call methods from the test2.ts methods that are in the test.ts file, vscode swears that the method is not declared, although the code is being executed.

.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from "vue"
  import test from "./test";

  export default defineComponent({

    methods: test.methods

  })
</script>
```

.test

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

import test2 from "./test2";
const custommethod2 : any = test2.methods

export default defineComponent({
    methods: {
        methods1() : void {
            console.log('methods1')
            this.methods3()
        },
        handleClick(term: any) {
            this.handleClick3()
        },

        methods2(){
            console.log('methods2')
        },
        ...custommethod2
    }

})
```

and

.test2

```
import { defineComponent } from "vue"


export default defineComponent({
    methods: {
        methods3() : void {
            console.log('methods')
        },
        handleClick3(term: any) {
            console.log('handleClick3')
            this.methods1()
        },

        methods23(){
            console.log('methods2')
            console.log(this.$data)
        }
    }

})
```

Property 'methods1' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, { methods3(): void; handleClick3(term: any): void; methods23(): void; }, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 11 more ..., {}>'

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins

Comment: thanks, i will be useed "extends"